# How to deform an object by collision with another object in a realistic way?

Tags: modeling, surface-deform

I'm using Blender for the first time to create a deformation in a mask model based on how it would realistically deform around a face model, for the purpose of designing around the deformed mask. What is the best way to do this? The shrink wrap modifier seems like the closest thing to what I'm looking for, but I still have not been able to make it work in the way I'd like.

Comment: Hello, maybe show some screenshots of your current objects?

Comment: What is the way you would like it to work?

Comment: Hi, Dot, and welcome. The devil really is in the detail, here. A 'mask model' could be quite a wide variety of things. Could you please illustrate, so respondents can pick out a suitable method?